# When to utilize pandas .filter() over other subsetting methods?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I've been studying the different ways to filter and subset pandas DataFrames and came across the [pandas.DataFrame.filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method. However, I can't figure out why one would use this over another method of filtering (loc, iloc, logical operators, str.contains(), .query(), etc). Can anyone provide an example of when it makes sense to use .filter() over the alternatives?

Comment: Within the pandas api there are numerous ways to do the exact same thing. Lately, the maintainers have been actively trying to deprecate duplicative methods in an attempt to simplify the library (i.e. removal of `lookup` and currently deprecating the `level` arguments of sum, mean, any, etc...). You can of course subset like `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('foo')]`, but for clarify and brevity `df.filter(like='foo')` is a bit better IMO

Comment: ^ And not to mention the `filter` method has a lot of extra error handling in case your column labels aren't strings

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is applied to index or column **labels**, not the values.

In contrast to `query`, `contains` etc. which are used to filter a `DataFrame` based on its contents.

If you for example would like to only keep columns ending with 'address', you could use `df.filter(regex='address$')`

Answer (score 0):

- Each function is used in particular circumstances. `Filter()` is useful for getting a large data down to a smaller size, based on the questions you want to ask. `Query()`, on the other hand, is useful for phrasing questions that use comparison operators (less than, equal to, greater than, etc.)
- The Pandas `Query()` method is a fantastic way to filter and query data. Unlike other Pandas methods, it uses a string argument that functions rather similar to `SQL` syntax.
- You should only use `Query()` when your question (query) can be posed as greater than, less than, equal to, or not equal to (or some combination of these).
- Use `filter()` when you want to get a quick sense of your dataset or, as we shall see, create a new dataframe based on the columns you want. It is particularly useful if your dataset has many columns. You can also use it to reorder your columns in a more desired way.

for more read [http://pandas.pythonhumanities.com][1]

[1]: [http://pandas.pythonhumanities.com/03_02_advanced_querying.html#:~:text=Filter()%20is%20useful%20for,greater%20than%2C%20etc.](http://pandas.pythonhumanities.com/03_02_advanced_querying.html#:%7E:text=Filter()%20is%20useful%20for,greater%20than%2C%20etc.)).